# Variance equivalences

Tags: calculus, statistics, variance

I am working through Foundation Maths seventh edition. I got stuck while trying to proof the following statement:

$∑(x - x̄)^2 = ∑(x^2) - n·x̄^2$

Is someone able to show what steps are needed to go from the absolute difference to $∑(x^2) - n·x̄^2$

Thank you!

Comment: Please learn *MathJax*.

Comment: My apologies, I have edited the post.

Comment: Expand the sum, and use the definition of mean

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum(x-\mu)^2=\sum x^2+\sum\mu^2-\sum2\mu x=\sum x^2+n\mu^2-2\mu\sum x$$

Recall now that:

$$\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum x,\quad n\mu=\sum x$$

Which implies the variance is:

$$\sum x^2+n\mu^2-2\mu(n\mu)=\sum x^2-n\mu^2$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I forgot that $\sum x$ can be written as $n×x$

Comment: @Sam This works in general with probability by the way: if $E$ denotes expected value, and $X$ any random variable with a probability distribution, then: $$\operatorname{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$$